# Flutter - Lag when ListView contains a lot of data

Tags: flutter, dart

My social media app crashes when there's too much data in the ListView, because I scroll down to see more content and so it's choppy. The code below is a widget located in the homepage. However, as the number of elements in the ListView increases, my application starts to slow down and not smooth. I want to improve the performance of my application and reduce lag
My social media app crashes when there's too much data in the ListView, because I scroll down to see more content and so it's choppy. The code below is a widget located in the homepage. However, as the number of elements in the ListView increases, my application starts to slow down and not smooth. I want to improve the performance of my application and reduce lag

```
class NewJobList extends StatefulWidget {
  final String nameMe;
  final String userId;
  const NewJobList({super.key, required this.userId, required this.nameMe});

  @override
  State<NewJobList> createState() => _NewJobListState();
}

class _NewJobListState extends State<NewJobList> {
  late PostFeeProvider postFeeProvider;
  final controller = ScrollController();
  bool isLoading = false;
  int pageLoad = 1;
  final dio = Dio();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    postFeeProvider = Provider.of<PostFeeProvider>(context, listen: false);
    postFeeProvider.getAllFeePost(pageLoad, true);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dio = Dio();
    return Consumer<PostFeeProvider>(
      builder: (context, postAllData, _) {
        return ListView.builder(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: postAllData.postFee.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final post = postAllData.postFee[index];

            Future<void> addBookmark() async {
              String postId = post.id;
              String current_user_id = widget.userId;
              try {
                var response = await dio.post(
                    "$baseUrl/saveBookmark/addBookmark/$current_user_id/$postId",
                    data: {});

                if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                  final snackBar = SnackBar(
                    elevation: 0,
                    behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    content: AwesomeSnackbarContent(
                      title: 'Thêm Bookmark thành công',
                      message: 'Bây giờ, Bạn có thể nhìn thấy bookmark đã lưu',
                      contentType: ContentType.success,
                    ),
                  );

                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                    ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
                    ..showSnackBar(snackBar);
                }
              } catch (e) {
                print(e);
              }
            }

            String emoji = post.emoji;
            final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
            final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
            final currentWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

            return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (_) => JobDetail(post: post),
                        ),
                      ),
                      updateView().whenComplete(
                          () => postFeeProvider.getAllFeePost(pageLoad, true)),
                    },
                child: IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    avatar(post),
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          nameAndTime(post),
                          titleAndprice(post),
                          description(post),
                          post.images.isNotEmpty
                              ? ListImages(post: post, indexColumn: index)
                              : const SizedBox(),

                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 70, top: 7, bottom: 30, right: 20),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 22,
                                  width: 20.84,
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    'assets/images/workpost_icon.png',
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: currentWidth * 0.01,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  post.applyCount.toString(),
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'AvertaStdCY-Semibold',
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: currentWidth * 0.03,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 22,
                                  width: 26.57,
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    'assets/images/eyepost_icon.png',
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: currentWidth * 0.01,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  post.view.toString(),
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'AvertaStdCY-Semibold',
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                      children: [
                                        GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            addBookmark();
                                          },
                                          child: SizedBox(
                                            height: 23,
                                            width: 24.64,
                                            child: Image.asset(
                                              'assets/images/savepost_icon.png',
                                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                          width: 16,
                                        ),
                                        PopupMenuButton<int>(
                                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                          ),
                                          onSelected: (value) {
                                            if (value == 1) {
                                              showGeneralDialog(
                                                  barrierLabel: "Barrier",
                                                  barrierDismissible: true,
                                                  barrierColor:
                                                      Colors.transparent,
                                                  transitionDuration:
                                                      const Duration(
                                                          milliseconds: 400),
                                                  context: context,
                                                  pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
                                                    return BlurredDialog(
                                                        dialogContent:
                                                            ReportPostDialog(
                                                      nameMe: widget.nameMe,
                                                      userId: widget.userId,
                                                      postId: post.id,
                                                    ));
                                                  },
                                                  transitionBuilder:
                                                      (_, anim, __, child) {
                                                    Tween<Offset> tween;

                                                    tween = Tween(
                                                        begin:
                                                            const Offset(0, 1),
                                                        end: Offset.zero);

                                                    return SlideTransition(
                                                      position: tween.animate(
                                                        CurvedAnimation(
                                                            parent: anim,
                                                            curve: Curves
                                                                .easeInOut),
                                                      ),
                                                      child: child,
                                                    );
                                                  });
                                            } else if (value == 2) {
                                              // Mục 2 được chọn
                                            } else if (value == 3) {
                                              print('3');
                                            }
                                          },
                                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                              [
                                            PopupMenuItem<int>(
                                              value: 1,
                                              child: Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  Image.asset(
                                                    "assets/images/warning_ic.png",
                                                    width: 30,
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    ' Báo cáo bài viết',
                                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                                      fontFamily:
                                                          'AvertaStdCY-Bold',
                                                      fontSize: 15,
                                                      color: Color(0xff3C3F42),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            PopupMenuItem<int>(
                                              value: 2,
                                              child: Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  Image.asset(
                                                    "assets/images/report_user_ico.png",
                                                    width: 30,
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    ' Báo cáo ${post.name}',
                                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                                      fontFamily:
                                                          'AvertaStdCY-Bold',
                                                      fontSize: 15,
                                                      color: Color(0xff3C3F42),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                        
                                          ],
                                          child: SizedBox(
                                            height: 23 * 0.8,
                                            width: 24.64 * 0.8,
                                            child: Image.asset(
                                              'assets/images/ellipsis_icon.png',
                                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                   
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )));
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

Widget avatar(PostAll post) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 20),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: 60,
          height: 60,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                child: Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  child: Image.network(
                    '${post.avatar}',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                  bottom: 3,
                  left: 27,
                  child: Lottie.asset("${post.emoji}", height: 30)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const Expanded(
            child: DottedDashedLine(
                height: double.infinity, width: 5, axis: Axis.vertical))
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Widget nameAndTime(PostAll post) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 70, right: 20),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          '@${formatUserName(post.name)}',
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'AvertaStdCY-Bold',
            fontSize: 15,
            color: Color(0xff3C3F42),
          ),
        ),
        if (post.verified == true)
          Image.asset(
            'assets/images/verified_acc.png',
            height: 19,
          ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 8, 0),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 5,
                    height: 5,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 30, 30, 30).withOpacity(0.8),
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    formatTimeDiffString(post.postingTime),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'AvertaStdCY-Regular',
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: Color(0xff3C3F42),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Widget description(PostAll post) {
  return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, left: 70, top: 5, bottom: 7),
      child: ExpandableText(
        text: post.content,
        maxLines: 5,
      ));
}

Widget titleAndprice(PostAll post) {
  String formatCurrency(int amount) {
    final formatter = NumberFormat("#,###");
    return formatter.format(amount).replaceAll(',', '.');
  }

  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 70, top: 5, right: 20),
    child: Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
          width: 3,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(34.26),
        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.15),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              "${post.title}",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'AvertaStdCY-Black',
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Giá: ",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'AvertaStdCY-Regular',
                    fontSize: 15,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "${formatCurrency(int.parse(post.price))} ₫ | ${post.adviseType}",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'AvertaStdCY-Extrabold',
                    fontSize: 15,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 3,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

**I have tried many ways but can't fix it if someone any way please help me, thank you!**

Answer (score 1):

This one isn't easy, because the data you are rendering in the `ListView` has dynamic size. I am working on a Mastodon client and did a combination of the following:

1. Work with `cacheExtend`. This property defines an area around the visible content of the ScrollView, for which content is already drawn by the render engine. I use a `cacheExtend` of 1000. For example. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/cacheExtent.html
2. Pre-cache images. As soon, as I load posts from the API, I add the preview images to the cache.
3. Do not load to big chunks. Work with a `ScrollController` and trigger loading of the next chunk, when you are close to the bottom of your `ListView`.
4. If possible, use the `Impeller` render engine.

```dart
 Future<void> _addPreviewToImageCache(
    String previewUrl,
    BuildContext buildContext,
  ) async {
    unawaited(
      precacheImage(
        NetworkImage(previewUrl),
        buildContext,
        onError: _handleImageLoadFailed,
      ),
    );
  }
```

```dart
void _scrollToBottomListener() {
    final scrolledToBottom = _scrollController.position.pixels ==
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
    if (scrolledToBottom) {
      final statusFeedBloc = context.read<StatusFeedBloc>();
      if (statusFeedBloc.state.status == StatusFeedStatus.success) {
        statusFeedBloc.add(StatusFeedLoadMoreRequested());
      }
    }
  }
```